# Laravel - Is it standard to use (one get and one post) in route instead of (resource and using only index and store)?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, resources

When I can use

```
Route::get('somewhere', function() {
    // show
});
Route::post('somewhere/search', function() {
    // search
});
```

So isn't it illogical to us `resource` for it when I want only two methods? and not using `only` for that?

Comment: No problem with that

Answer (score 0):

It is `best practices` not to put implementation in `route` file as it grows bigger day by day and became `unfeasible` to handle. You could use normal controller for that-

```
Route::get('somewhere','SomeController@somewhere');
Route::post('somewhere/search', 'SomeController@somewhereSearch');
```